# How to pass Java List to Scala, filter it in Scala and get back to Java?

Tags: java, list, scala, filter

For example:

```
package example.javascala.list;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class UseScalaList {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = {"a", "very", "long", "list", "of", "words"};
    List<String> lst = Arrays.asList(words);  

    // Call Scala code here to filter word "a" from Java list and return back List<String> ?           
}
}
```

Questions:

- Scala object to filter `java.util.List<String>`
- How to call Scala and get filtered list back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import scala.collection.*;

Collection<String> filtered = JavaConversions.asJavaCollection(JavaConversions.asScalaIterable(lst).filter(...));
```

**UPDATE**:

```
Iterable<String> scalaIterable = JavaConversions.asScalaIterable(lst);
scalaIterable.filter(...);
scalaIterable.drop(1);
scalaIterable.somethingMore(...);

Collection<String> backToJava = JavaConversions.asJavaCollection(scalaIterable);
```

Comment: Qool oneliner! And what if I need to do several list transformations in Scala, ang get result back to Java. How to define a separate Scala object with several methods with List<String> arg to be called from Java?

Comment: Thanks! Not quite the answer I expected though. In your examples there is only Java code. It would be interesting to see a user-defined (not standard Scala library) Scala object encapsulating list manipulation. In other words Java only calls use-defined API on Scala object with implementation in Scala. For example Scala object may have `process(lst: List)` method. This method gets Java list, and does function composition on it such as `map.filter. ...`. How this _Scala object_ would look like?